# I have a Mesh with an Armature. The Mesh has a "Mesh Deform" modifier, which itself has physics. Why does it break when Rendered?

Tags: rendering, animation, armature, physics

I am probably missing something very obvious---maybe a modifier stack problem, more likely it's a parenting issue, or else I don't understand Mesh Deform well enough.

**This is a simplified example. Wiggle bones are not appropriate for my problem.** Let's pretend we MUST use Soft Body physics on a Mesh Deform cage.

I have a complex mesh with an armature. To give PARTS of it soft body physics, I have a Mesh Deform cage surrounding one part of the Mesh, so that poor old blender doesn't have to worry about squishing and pulling a trillion polygons. The Mesh Deform cage is parented to a bone in the Mesh's Armature so that it follows the Mesh appropriately. The Mesh Deform cage has Soft Body physics. I'm trying to cheese it so that only **parts** of the High Poly Mesh behave with soft body physics, without having to calculate that.

[image: preview mode of a Mesh Deform Cage around a High Poly Mesh with an Armature]

[image: preview mode of a Mesh Deform Cage around a High Poly Mesh with an Armature]

It seems fine, perfect even... until I render it. Rendering it breaks it.

[image: Broken Render of a Mesh Deform Cage around a High Poly Mesh with an Armature]

**The Soft Body Physics is baked, and I have tried it without baking, too.** It feels like a parenting issue, or something about vertexes and weight painting?

I have tried many things, and followed other threads with **similar** problems, but no one is asking this, specifically, that I could find. I apologize if this has been answered. If it has, I would like a simpler answer, explained like I'm five, because the complexity of rigging is very confusing for me.

If there is an amazing alternative for cheesing/faking soft body physics (capable of collision) on PARTS of a complex mesh **which isn't wiggle bones**, I am all ears.

I am so confused, sorry about this.

https://file.io/mw7LWq7f04QD this is a link to the blend file

Comment: Check for modifiers that are hidden in the viewport  but enabled in render 

Comment: I checked, they're all visible for rendering , the problem persists :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update Blender.

For future reference, the above set-up works. If anyone in the future is having trouble figuring out Mesh Deform with Armatures, I hope these pictures and descriptions help. Just make sure you've updated Blender.

And make sure you Bake any physics or wiggle bones before rendering.

Comment: Well, you’re not an idiot because the Lord doesn’t make idiots, and He made you. Easy mistake. God bless!